# Error in test cases for a recursion problem

Tags: java, recursion

I am solving a code for competitive programming and my code which I think is correct is throwing an error for some test cases: 
The question is to find the total number of digits in an integer using recursion.

My Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Driver_class
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();

        while(t-- > 0)
        {
            int n =sc.nextInt();  // taking number "n" as input
            System.out.println(new Digitcount().countDigits(n)); // prints the count of digits 
        }
    }
}


class Digitcount
{
    static int count=0;
    public static int countDigits(int n)
    {
        if(n<1)
            return 0;
        countDigits(n/10);
        count++;
        return count;
    }
}
```

The count variable is the total number of digits.
The test case that this code fails:
[image: failed test case]

However, this code passes all the test cases:

```
class Digitcount
{
    static int count=0;
    public static int countDigits(int n)
    {
        if(n<1)
            return 0;
        return countDigits(n/10)+1;
    }
}
```

I dont see a difference in any of my codes regarding the output value. What is causing the first code to fail the test case?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in use of a static variable. It will hold the result between tests and thus in any test after the first one it will be incorrect. If you have two calls one after the other like so:

```
int a = countDigits(605);    
int b = countDigits(605);
```

The result will be `a==3`, `b==6` - the first result is carried over to the second call.

Comment: but for the second call, wouldn't  the static variable count  be reassigned to zero. The function call is made in another class from main method. I have reuploaded the whole code of my program.

Comment: @dFuse_mArv That is the whole idea of a static variable - it keeps it's state between calls to the fuction for the whole life of a program. The assigned 0 is there only on the first run. If you want to change it back to 0 afterwards, you have to call `count=0` explicitly somewhere else - initialization of static variables is performed only once in "life span" of a program.